# Making plot on different charts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

my problem is that when i show my plots pandas draws them on each other. I want them to be on different charts. How to do that?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')

survived = train[train['Survived'] == 1] # saving in variable all the people that survived
not_survived = train[train['Survived'] == 0] # saving in variable all the people that have not survived

tab = pd.crosstab(train['Pclass'], train['Sex'])
tab.div(tab.sum(1).astype(float), axis=0).plot(kind="bar", stacked=False)


train.groupby('Embarked').Survived.mean().plot(kind='line')
```

Chart that i get
[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot.html?highlight=subplots) help you?

Comment: I'm using plot inside pandas that uses matplotlib. How can i combine that to work as i want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you incorporate multiple axes with pandas plot

```
survived = train[train['Survived'] == 1] # saving in variable all the people that survived
not_survived = train[train['Survived'] == 0] # saving in variable all the people that have not survived

tab = pd.crosstab(train['Pclass'], train['Sex'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, figsize = (10,5))

tab.div(tab.sum(1).astype(float), axis=0).plot(kind="bar", stacked=False, ax = ax[0])

train.groupby('Embarked').Survived.mean().plot(kind='line', ax = ax[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you know how to make those plots drawn not together in one image?